# What is PriorityVertex?

Tags: java, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

What is the type PriorityVertex as seen here? I am also writing a getMinSpanningTree method.

[Prim's Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750069/prims-algorithm/23578963#23578963)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PriorityVertex` from this example is just a class that the asker created. It is a simple implementation of a vertex in a graph.

This class implements the `Comparable` interface. The reason for that is that `PriorityQueue` must compare its elements. This can be achieved in two ways:

- The elements must either implement the `Comparable` interface
- **or** a `Comparator` has to be passed to the `PriorityQueue`, that tells the queue how to compare the elements.

So the `PriorityVertex` class could **roughly** look as follows:

```
class PriorityVertex implements Comparable<PriorityVertex>
{
    private float priority;

    // Setters, getters ... whatever the vertex needs
    ...

    // Implementation of the Comparable interface:
    @Override 
    public int compareTo(PriorityVertex other)
    {
        return Float.compare(this.priority, other.priority);
    }
}
```